# SQL display all (including original) duplicates IF distinct value in a field

Tags: sql, duplicates, ms-access-2007, syntax-error

I am using Access 2007 and new to SQL.  I have a table in which I wish to identify any rows where customer name and part number match, but location does not.  The application is to easily identify price differences if the same part is ordered by the same customer, but sent to another location.  My query returns the below information if I do Not include the last line of code:

```
   CustomerNumber CompanyName PartNumber CustomerName Location SumOfQuantity AvgOfPrice
   5            Prestige    1000-A-26631-0  FINLAND OY  FINLAND 1            $5.00
   5            Prestige    1000-A-26631-0  FINLAND OY  KARHULA 2            $10.00
   15           Prestige    1000-A-29230-0  Portland    (US)    2            $15.00
   3            Prestige    1000-A-29230-0  BARBOU      BARBOU  2            $5.00
   9            Prestige    1000-A-29230-0  MEXICO      MEXICO  6            $20.00
```

The first two rows are exactly what I'm looking for.  The CustomerName and PartNumber match, but the Location is different.  However, my query is also returning rows in which the PartNumbers match, but the CustomerNames do not.  I believe I have to add a similar Group By, HAVING COUNT statement for CustomerName as well, but I am getting a syntax error.  I imagine the solution is embarrassingly simple, but haven't been able to figure it out.  Can anyone help identify why I am getting the error?

SQL:

```
SELECT [2-B: Avg Prices by Customer].[Customer Number], [2-B: Avg Prices by Customer].[Company Name], *
FROM [2-B: Avg Prices by Customer]
WHERE ((([2-B: Avg Prices by Customer].[Company Name])=[Forms]![Start Form]![Combo73]))
OR ((([2-B: Avg Prices by Customer].[Company Name])=[Forms]![Start Form]![List67])
AND (([2-B: Avg Prices by Customer].[Part Number]) In 
(SELECT [Part Number] FROM [2-B: Avg Prices by Customer] 
GROUP BY [Part Number] HAVING COUNT([Part Number]) >1)), 
[Customer Name] HAVING COUNT([Customer Name])>1))); ------ > **Syntax error here, missing operator**
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  CustomerName,
  PartNumber
FROM [2-B: Avg Prices by Customer] p
GROUP BY CustomerName,PartNumber
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Location) > 1
```